# Carrying tea tree oil while traveling from London to India

Tags: air-travel, luggage, india

I'm wondering whether there will be a problem during luggage check-in (carry on) if I carry multiple bottles (max 3 bottles each 100mL) of Tea Tree oil.

Comment: Are you talking about check-in or carry-on luggage?

Comment: Check-in luggage.

Comment: OK. So are you worried about the airline not allowing you to pack the oil? Or the customs checks upon arrival in India?

Comment: Both. As I can have multiple bottles that's why I'm thinking.

Comment: (IMO) Unless it is an illegal or controlled product in India, you should not have any problems; 300 ml of an alternative medicine product is not that much quantity.

Comment: Okay.. It's nothing illegal, it's just a herbal oil.

Comment: Boots sells tea tree oil and there is a boots outlet in the duty free area if you are worried about security wasting your time. Make sure they have it in stock by giving them a call.

Comment: @JonathanReez: I don't think Tea tree oil can be categorized in medicine. It's a herbal oil. What's your opinion.

Answer (score 8):

According to the [Australian Tee Tree industry website](http://www.teatree.org.au/downloads/dangerous_goods.pdf):

> *Why is tea tree oil classified as a dangerous good?*
>
> **It has flammable properties, with a FLASH POINT (closed cup) under
> 60.5°C. According to the IATA DGR liquids having flash point less or equal to 60.5°C are classified as dangerous goods (Class 3).**
>
> ...
>
> *How may dangerous goods be transported by air?*
>
> **They are not permitted in passengers' or crews' baggage.**

Therefore the answer is **no**, you may not carry tea tree oil in your carry-on or check-in luggage, as it is a highly flammable liquid.

[Websites selling tea tree oil](http://www.brambleberry.com/Tea-Tree-Essential-Oil-P3834.aspx) confirm it as well:

> NOTE: This low-flashpoint oil (136°F) will ship Ground Only, regardless of the shipping method you choose at checkout. It cannot ship outside the lower 48 U.S. states or USPS.

Comment: Your first link is broken.

Answer (score -5):

You will have absolutely no problem with carrying tree tea oil in your checking luggage. If you can have the receipts of the product with you that would be great if in case the customs has any questions, which I doubt. Just make sure you pack it properly (Leak proof).

Comment: Do you have any references for these claims?

Comment: @Bill.. Thanks. I will keep the bills for safety.